# Change ListViewItem Bounds

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

Is there any way to set the bounds of a all ListView items in LargeIcon mode to a specific size?

I want to manually draw a rounded rectangle background for each of the items, but in the DrawItem event e.Bounds differs based on the state of the items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SystemInformation.IconSpacingSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.iconspacingsize.aspx) to discover the size of the grid square used to arrange icons in LargeIcon mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but here is another problem: When the item state is "Selected" e.Bounds of the DrawItem event is set to a different size and if I fill a rectangle with the size that I retrieved from SystemInformation only the size that e.Bound is set to will be painted.

Comment: Yes, the icon text for a selected item is allowed to be longer than 2 lines of text.  I think your problem is that the clipping region will be set to e.Bounds, you can't draw outside of the bounds.  I don't see an obvious workaround for this.