# change OwnerDraw ListViewItem Bounds

Tags: c#, winforms, listviewitem, ownerdrawn

I have a ownerdrawing ListView with LargeIcon view mode and want to change ListViewItem's bounds property. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896707/change-listviewitem-bounds) link does not help me, because the property SystemInformation.IconSpacingSize is read only.
I need to have all 150x220px icons for drawing. 
Is there any ways or tricks for solving my problem?

Comment: Could you share some of your code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigne an [ImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx) component to the [ListView.LargeImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.largeimagelist.aspx) property. If you draw images manually, there is not need to populate the ImageList with images. It is only important to set an appropriate value to the [ImageList.ImageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagesize.aspx) property. ListView items will be resized correspondingly.